# Ошибка при получении данных с таблицы бд использующей kalnoy/nestedset

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, nested-sets

Использую kalnoy/nestedset для реализации групп и не понимаю почему моё обращение для получения групп вываливает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Конечно же у меня не определён метод юзерс, но при этом он вообще не имеет никакого отношения к этой модели и нигде не вызывается :\
К слову метод контроллера который выдал мне ошибку на данный момент выглядит так:

```
public function index(ListProjectGroupRequest $request)
    {
        dd(ProjectGroup::all());
    }
```

Реквест спокойно меня пускает и как указано в stack trace, то это как раз метод который в виде кода выше. Я не совсем понимаю почему это происходит и как это решить. Не могу найти ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста если видели такое или есть идеи

**UPD: забыл упомянуть, что я испытываю такие трудности только с обычным пользователем, но при этом админ этих проблем не испытывает. Также я не знаю почему.**